# using of nant in c#.net

Tags: c#, .net, ant, nant

i have a following xml file which said to be as

```
<target name="run-command">
  <exec program="D:\ib2cmd.bat" basedir=".">
  </exec>
</target>
```

and placed in the project file

then i set the environment variable for nant-0.92-bin path in system variables.

finally i called from c# through

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("nant.exe -buildfile: d:xxx/xx/xxx.xml");
```

while iam running this i got error as

```
INVALID INPUT FILE PATH
```

i do not know where i went wrong

waiting for your valuable suggestions and comments

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code - based on ProcessStartInfo

```
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("nant.exe");
        startInfo.Arguments = "/-buildfile  \"d:\\xxx\\xx\\xxx.xml\"";
        Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Lanuch Bat

```
 <target name="run-command">
   <exec program="..." basedir=".">
     <arg value="" />
   </exec>
 </target>
```

Comment: thanks foe you help getting error as The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: Adjust your path  of tool just this, happy to help you GowthamanSS

Comment: i need to run only one bat file is it possible through nant

Comment: if possible can you update me ur c# code with nant xml file for running bat file which will help me

Comment: i add nother code GowthamanSS, in your code you don't add arg section

Comment: where shall i add the target name file

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17222/discussion-between-gowthamanss-and-aghilas-yakoub)

Answer (score 0):

I better to use:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("nant.exe -buildfile: \"d:\\xxx\\xx\\xxx.xml\"");
```

I think that the command line is not getting the path correctly because is not in windows format.